# Windows 10 installation stuck

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-installation

I have an an715-51, with 2 SSDs.
I had to format them and I can't install windows 10 again.
It gets stuck on the 2nd step, "getting ready for windows installation".
I tried 3 different usb sticks to make the bootable media, all with the same issue, but at different percentage. Some get stuck at 17%, some at 21% some 94%. I can provide you with any required logs or dumps or stuffs, just kindly help me fix this.

Comment: Have you taken a backup of the disk before wiping everything (if yes, restore it)? Why did you need to format?

Comment: Malware infected the previous os so I decided to reinstallm

Comment: Why couldn't reset to a clean image? Your symptoms look like the installation media lacks some driver.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue writing windows 10 over raid 0.
It showed my 2 512gb ssds as 1 1tb ssd.
Probably my previous Setup was done installing raid0 after windows.
Basically my raid was on  RST Premium with optane mode.
An engineer helped me out, he switched the mode to ahci, created partitions,  drives were now seperated into 2, then restarted to rst+optane mode. Then installed windows 10 doing normal partitioning, and it installed. Without any issues.

Hope it helps anyone with similar issues